# Error connecting Phoenix to Secure HBase on MapR cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, mapr

Whenever I try connecting to secure HBase, I get the following error.
started Phoenix using command: ./sqlline.py :5181:/hbase::
Port used is 5181 because it is MapR hadoop. HBase version is 1.1.1 and Phoenix version is 4.8.1.

Phoenix worked without any issues before implementing Kerberos.  And the jdbc url we passed to unsecure cluster was, ./sqlline.py :5181

I have executed the command kinit on all nodes before starting Phoenix.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

ERROR LOG:

> WARN ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>   FATAL ipc.AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>           at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:612)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:157)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:738)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:735)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:735)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:897)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:866)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1209)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:217)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:318)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:32831)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:373)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:200)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:350)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:324)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
>           at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
>           at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
>           at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
>           at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
>           at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
>           at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
>           at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
>           ... 26 more

Comment: you may want to check the user you are executing sqlline as

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is the same user configured for HBase

Comment: @PriyankaKhandelwal, did you find the solution? I am facing similar issue